# Simple $\mathfrak{g}$-modules preserved by twisting

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semi-simple lie group (simply connected for simplicity), $\mathfrak{g}$ its lie algebra.  Write $\overline{G}=Inn(\mathfrak{g})$ for the adjoint form of $G$ which we identify here with the group of inner automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$.

For a representation $M$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ and an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, define the twisting of $M$ by $\varphi$ as the $\mathfrak{g}$ module $M^{\varphi}$, which as a vector space is $M$ and the $\mathfrak{g}$-action is given by $X\cdot m=\varphi^{-1}(X)m$ (the inverse is to simplify things later).  Note that if $M$ is infinite-dimensional this twist may not be isomorphic to $M$.

Now suppose that $M$ is a simple representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that for every inner automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, we have an isomorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $M^{\varphi}\cong M$.  By Schur's lemma, the isomorphism $M^{\varphi}\to M$ is unique up to a nonzero scalar, hence we obtain a map $\overline{G}\to PGL(M)$.  One can check that this is in fact an homomorphism of groups.

My question is: how does this projective representation of $G$ relate to the originally defined $\mathfrak{g}$-representation?  I would really like the following to be true: in the given situation, we in fact must have that $M$ is integrable (i.e. a direct sum of finite-dimensional representations), and hence the projective representation $\overline{G}\to PGL(M)$ is coming from a representation of $G$ on $M$.

However some obvious difficulties are that we know nothing about the map $\overline{G}\to PGL(M)$ besides that it is a group homomorphism, and further with $M$ infinite dimensional, I don't know of a natural topology to put on $PGL(M)$.

Comment: Probably if $M$ arises as the smooth vectors in a Hilbert-space, Banach-space, or Frechet-space repn of the group $G$, you'd want the natural Frechet-space structure. And the topology in which $G\to PGL(M)$ is continuous is rarely any sort of "operator norm topology" (which doesn't make much sense anyway for Frechet M), but "strong operator topology", which does make sense for Frechet repns. I'd wager this is what you want for your set-up.

Comment: Is it possible to always realize $M$ as such a representation of $G$?  Unfortunately here I don't want to assume anything extra about $M$.

Comment: No, there are definitely repns of Lie algebras that do not come from repns of the Lie group. Some can be realized by repns on the universal covering space/group of the Lie algebra... but I am not confident that _all_ can be.

Comment: I agree.  However I am asking that $M$ has this extra property that $M^{\varphi}\cong M$ for all inner automorphisms $\varphi$.  I have not been able to find an example of a simple representation $M$ with this property that is not finite dimensional.